# how to show data by pieces in BarChart Android

Tags: android, charts, android-design-library

I have a problem with BarChart.. I have a 7 item on list. For example

```
final int[] a = {5,2,10,4,7,8,13};
final String[] b= {"January","February","March","April","May","June","Jully"};
```

So I want to show by pieces on Barchart. For example first 5 items show and when I click the button than 2 items remaining show in Barchart. Images is,
[image]

**Than I want when I click the "WAFAW" button barchart is,**

[image]

But my code working is,

[image]

So it means dont show the bar..How can I do that? Thanks for now..

My Code is,

```
final BarChart barChart = (BarChart) findViewById(R.id.chart);
Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);


final int[] a = {5,2,10,4,7,8,13};
final String[] b= {"January","February","March","April","May","June","Jully"};
final ArrayList<BarEntry> entries = new ArrayList<>();
final ArrayList<String> labels = new ArrayList<String>();

for(int i=0 ; i<5;i++){
    entries.add(new BarEntry(a[i],i));
    labels.add(b[i]);
}
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        entries.clear();
        labels.clear();

        for(int i=5; i<a.length;i++){
            entries.add(new BarEntry(a[i],i));
            labels.add(b[i]);
        }
        BarDataSet dataset = new BarDataSet(entries, "# of Calls");
        barChart.getXAxis().setPosition(XAxis.XAxisPosition.TOP);
        BarData data = new BarData(labels, dataset);
        dataset.setColors(ColorTemplate.COLORFUL_COLORS);
        barChart.setData(data);
        barChart.animateY(3000);
    }
});

BarDataSet dataset = new BarDataSet(entries, "# of Calls");

barChart.getXAxis().setPosition(XAxis.XAxisPosition.TOP);

BarData data = new BarData(labels, dataset);
dataset.setColors(ColorTemplate.COLORFUL_COLORS);
barChart.setData(data);

barChart.animateY(3000);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know there is no simple solution on how to select which bars to display. It depends on how dynamically you want/need to solve it.

The best solution I can think of would be keeing an array of bars to show like:

```
final int[] show_arr = {0,1,2,3,4,5};
```

and when `onClick()` is called you change the array to

```
final int[] show_arr = {5,7};
```

and then you run through the whole plotting routine again.
But you add the entries with looping through `show_arr`

I know this is not a super nice solution, but at least you only have to code the vector hard and can reuse all the other parts.

Comment: Have you tried to add just barChart.invalicate();
What happens in your application

Comment: I dont tried because when I write a "barChart.invalicate();" I have a syntax error cause "cannot find symbol method invalicate() "..

please can u see the photo.. it means I create barChart but when I click the "WAFAW" button dont show anything..

Comment: I meant "barChart.invalidate()"

Comment: ok than. I solved this problem Julian59189.. My problem is seconf for loop. it means I started i=5 in fro loop and than I set BarChart start 5 index. But BarChart must be start 0 index. So that's why my problem. Thanks for to all advice..

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code for the same :

https://github.com/blackfizz/EazeGraph

https://github.com/HackPlan/AndroidCharts